# Objectify projection query with id as well in the result

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

How should a projection query be written in objectify, such that, the id of the entity also comes along in the result? (Projection query because my table has a lot of columns)

The query that I've written is

```
ofy().load().type(Item.class).filter("shopId",shopId)
    .filter("name >=",name)
    .filter("name <=",name+"\ufffd")
    .order("-creationTime")
    .project("name","imageUrl").list();
```

I've read putting id in the project function doesn't work. What's the workout to it, so that I get the name, imageUrl and the id as well?

Answer (score 3):

My bad. The id does come along in the result. You don't need to put id in the project function.